# Having serverside Paging and client side filtering

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I am having a KENDO UI Grid in which i have server side paging and this works fine. I return 8 records everytime.

Now before this I had client side pagination and it worked. Also I have filtering with `filterable: true` option. This works in client side.

Now after having the pagination moved to server side the filtering at client side does not seem to work. At least the client side filtering should work within a single page is what I would expect.

I couldnt find any documentation that says that client side filtering will not work with server side pagination.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like you are right. Applying a client side filter seems to break pagination. It probably filters the stuff sent back from the server, then recalculates the number of pages based on that (meaning there will only ever be one page). However I am curious what you would expect to happen with client side filtering. If the server returns 100 results and it is set to 10 per page (so 10 pages of 10 items), then you set a filter that eliminates every results, would you expect the UI to show 10 pages, with every page having 0 items? That seems like it would be an odd user experience.

Comment: I guessed the same only. It does not make sense to have pagination at server side and filtering in client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could be an "intended" feature.  If you think about it, you wouldn't want to apply paging *before* filtering your results.  I would probably delegate both of these functions to the server-side.